# Why does not a remove call to this Treeset effectively removes the element?

Tags: java

I was trying earlier to code a Dijkstra algorithm and faced out a problem with my implementation. I finally found a solultion but am still puzzled with the behaviour of the code.

What I am trying to do here is to iteratively *mark* the elements of a tree set. Everytime I mark an element, I remove it from the set and reinsert it, so the set places it at the end of the set (as the *compareTo* method tells it to do).
Doing so, I can take the first element of the set inside a *while* loop and stop when this first element is *marked*.

The following example is a minimal example:

```
public static void main(final String[] args) {
    Set<Element> elements = new TreeSet<>();
    elements.add(new Element(1));
    elements.add(new Element(2));
    elements.add(new Element(3));
    elements.add(new Element(5));
    elements.add(new Element(4));
    System.err.println(elements.size());
    while(!elements.iterator().next().mark){
        Element element = elements.iterator().next();
        element.mark();
        elements.remove(element);
        elements.add(element);
    }
    System.err.println(elements.size());
}

private static class Element implements Comparable<Element>{

    private boolean mark = false;
    private final int id;

    public Element(int id){
        this.id = id;
    }

    public void mark(){
        this.mark = true;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean equals(Object o){
        Element other = (Element) o;
        if(this.mark == other.mark){
            return this.id == other.id;
        } else {
            return false;
        }
    }

    @Override
    public int compareTo(Element other){
        if(this.mark == other.mark){
            return this.id - other.id;
        } else if(this.mark && !other.mark){
            return 1;
        } else {
            return -1;
        }
    }
}
```

The problem here is that the line :

```
elements.remove(element);
```

Does **not** remove the element. However, running it in a debugger, I can see that the element has the exact same reference as the element in the set and is equal to it with respect to the *equals* method. So, when running the line :

```
elements.add(element);
```

The same element is added two times ; because I suppose that the insertion in a tree set uses a binary search and does not test the equality between the first element of the set and the newly inserted one.

I have understood that swapping the two lines :

```
element.mark();
elements.remove(element);
```

Actually solves the problem.

My question though is : why does a modified element of a tree set is not effectively removed when modified through an iterator ?

Comment: `TreeSet` uses `compareTo`, not `equals`, so ignore the `equals` part. Now, you're mutating `mark` within your loop, which logically changes where it is within the ordered set... which you shouldn't do.

Comment: If it doesn't remove the element before you mark it, then there is some bug in your equals or compareTo method since that's how TreeSet knows when to remove something

Comment: @JonSkeet I understand that I should not do it. But in this case should not Java throw me a ConcurrentModificationException ?

Comment: @cricket_007 It *does* remove the element before I mark it, it however *does not* remove the element *after* I mark it.

Comment: No - you're not making a structural change to the set; you're just modifying the internals of an object in a way which affects sorting. How would you expect the set to notice that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`TreeSet` uses `compareTo` in order to position the elements in a tree structure (and also to determine equality). If you put an element in the `TreeSet` and then modify a property that is used in your `compareTo` method (i.e. the mark in your case), `remove` can't locate that element, since it looks for it in a different location than the one in which the original element was inserted.

If you remove the element before changing it, you solve the problem, since the original element is found were it was inserted.

Comment: you also cannot remove elements from a set while iterating over it. Use `it.remove()` to remove the current element from a set.

Comment: @NielsBillen You actually *can*, at least in this example. As explained, swapping the remove and mark lines *does* compile, execute and work as expected.

Comment: @DavidFournier As I said in the last sentence, removing the element before modifying it solves the problem. I'm assuming that's what you mean by "You actually can".